# JQuery Validation for Two Password Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Two entered passwords should be the same, and I want to display a notification when they're not matching. The target is to display the notification during typing and not after pressing the save Button.

I am new to javascript and I have also tried the functionname function() notation.

following js:

```
function updateError (error) {
if (error == true) {
    $(".error").hide(500);
}else{
 $(".error").show(500);
}
};

function checkSame() {
   var passwordVal = $("input[name=password-check]").val();
   var checkVal = $("input[name=password]").val();
   if (passwordVal == checkVal) {
     return true;
   }
   return false;
};


document.ready(function(){
 $("input[name=password-check]").keyup(function(){updateError(checkSame());});
 $("input[name=password]").keyup(function(){updateError(checkSame());});
});
```

and HTML:

```
 @Html.Password("password") 
 @Html.Password("password-check")     
 <span class="error">Errortext</span> </td></tr>
```

but it doesn't works..
Thx!

Edit:
Now i've changed the JS code to:

$("input[name=password-check]").keyup(function(){updateError(checkSame());});
 $("input[name=password]").keyup(function(){updateError(checkSame());});

--> now it works, but only once, after the user typed a matching password, validation stops working

Solved, problem was Quoting:

```
$("input[name='password-check']").keyup(function(){updateError(checkSame());});
$("input[name='password']").keyup(function(){updateError(checkSame());});
```

Comment: Good. But what is the question?

Comment: nothing happens if i change the passwords..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing opposite

```
if (error == true) {
    $(".error").show(500);
}else{
 $(".error").hide(500);
 }
```

Edit as per comment :

Try placing name within quotes like

```
$("input[name='password-check']").keyup(function(){updateError(checkSame());});
$("input[name='password']").keyup(function(){updateError(checkSame());});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the checkSame, you may want to use indexOf to check if passwordVal contains checkVal since when typing, the password is not equal yet.

```
   if (passwordVal.indexOf(checkVal)>-1 || checkVal.indexOf(passwordVal)>-1  ) {
     return true;
   }
```

Comment: Note that indexOf is not supported everywhere: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 0):

As int2000 said, fire the checkSame on keyup seems weird, but if it's what you want, OK.
Try to change your checkSame function as follows:

```
function checkSame() {
   var passwordVal = $("input[name=password-check]").val();
   var checkVal = $("input[name=password]").val();
   if (passwordVal == checkVal) {
     return false;
   }
   return true;
};
```

Remember that you're passing the result of checkSame to updateError, so if the passwords are the same you have no error.